# Aurelia-cli, babel-plugin-istanbul, Karma code-coverage Report always returns 100%

Tags: karma-jasmine, babeljs, istanbul, aurelia

Getting 100% coverage always.

The karma.conf.js file is same as what aurelia-cli generates.

I want to use babel-plugin-istanbul is code coverage reporting.

package.json ~~> node module used

```
"babel-plugin-istanbul": "^1.0.3",
"jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
"karma": "^0.13.22",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^1.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
"karma-babel-preprocessor": "^6.0.1",
"karma-coverage": "^1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.0",
"karma-sinon": "^1.0.5",
"sinon": "^1.17.4"
```

karma.conf.js (it is same as generated by aurelia-cli)

```
"use strict";
const path = require('path');
const project = require('./aurelia_project/aurelia.json');

let testSrc = [
  { pattern: project.unitTestRunner.source, included: false },
  'test/aurelia-karma.js'
];

let output = project.platform.output;
let appSrc = project.build.bundles.map(x => path.join(output, x.name));
let entryIndex = appSrc.indexOf(path.join(output, project.build.loader.configTarget));
let entryBundle = appSrc.splice(entryIndex, 1)[0];
let files = [entryBundle].concat(testSrc).concat(appSrc);

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: [project.testFramework.id, 'sinon'],
    files: files,
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {
      [project.unitTestRunner.source]: [project.transpiler.id]
    },
    'babelPreprocessor': { options: project.transpiler.options },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

The cover.js file

```
export function cover(done) {
  new Karma({
    configFile: __dirname + '/../../karma.conf.js',
    singleRun: true,
    reporters: ['coverage'],
    preprocessors: {
      'test/unit/**/*.js': ['babel'],
      'src/**/*.js': ['babel']
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      includeAllSources: true,
      reporters: [
        {type: 'html', dir: 'coverage'},
        {type: 'text'}
      ]
    }
  }, done).start();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need not include tests in preprocessors section. So, remove the first line and keep only the source code. The coverage is only about source code and not test methods.

```
preprocessors: {

      'src/**/*.js': ['babel']
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are missing at least the preprocessor for coverage:

```
preprocessors: {
  'test/unit/**/*.js': ['babel'],
  'src/**/*.js': ['babel', 'coverage']
},
```

That said, I was having similar issues even with that in place.

The main issue is that the default aurelia-cli setup for karma uses the app bundle as sources to run the tests from. That is not instrumented using `isparta` with this approach.

I have a working configuration as follows:

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import {Server as Karma} from 'karma';
import {CLIOptions} from 'aurelia-cli';

let appBundle = "scripts/app-bundle.js";


export function cover(done) {
  new Karma({
    configFile: __dirname + '/../../karma.conf.js',
    singleRun: !CLIOptions.hasFlag('watch'),
    reporters: ['coverage'],
    logLevel: 'debug',
    preprocessors: {
      [project.unitTestRunner.source]: [project.transpiler.id],
      [appBundle]: ['coverage']
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      includeAllSources: true,
      instrumenters: {
        isparta: require('isparta')
      },
      instrumenter: {
        [appBundle]: 'isparta'
      },
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html', dir: '.reports/coverage' },
        { type: 'text' }
      ]
    }
  }, done).start();
}

export default cover;
```

With this in place, I can run tests with coverage. Alas, the coverage report is based on the single `app-bundle.js` file, which doesn't give you itemised reports of each source file. But it's good enough to find key gaps in coverage, which is what I mainly use it for.

Comment: I've seen multiple approaches to getting code coverage in Aurelia, and this is the only one that's worked for me. Thank you!